# MITSUBISHI ASX 2012, Diesel - Engine performance around 2000 rpm

Tags: engine, mitsubishi

My ASX 2012 car is running strange when it's around 2k rpm. It doesn't mather what gear the car is in. Below and above it seems totaly fine.
I lack the propper English word for it, but the car gets "jaggy"/stalls/jerking when trying to drive around that rpm.

It's manual transmission. When driving around 2,5k rpm everything is just fine.

After this problem started, it sometimes takes 10-15 sec to start the car. And other times it starts normal in 2 seconds.

Any sugestions? Fairly skilled diy mechanic.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What has the maintenance record for the vehicle been like? Has there been any cleaner run through the system, like an anti-stiction (sp) (Howes Meaner Power Cleaner comes to mind)? Has the fuel filter been changed?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The car have taken all services that it are recomended. I did think it could be water in the diesel, so i have used diesel cleaner, that should also remove water. Have driven it for about half of tank, and its still the same.

Comment: This is a new behavior? If so, how long has it been doing it? Are there any codes?  Is this an automatic or standard shift transmission?

Comment: Yes this is a new behavior. For 1 week. No codes, and it's manual transmision. I'v ordered a new Odb2 thats designed for this car to, so maybe some info there. But no warning msg on dashboard.

Comment: That said when it started (last Friday): I had filled the tank up from 3/4 to full. Then was driving for about 2 hours around 80 km/h or 40 mph, mostly with cruise control in 6th gear when i started to see these signs. Then after 3 hour at same speed, i added the diesel cleaner. Then when back home on Sunday. In total driven about 1/2 of the diesel. a) water or b) filled the tank with 1/4 of petrol?? Suddenly i got real unsure about the filling. Was some stress at that point and no recite.

Comment: Wife says its been like this for a while. So not related to last diesel filling.